# In Linux, I'm looking for a way for one process to signal another, with blocking

Tags: linux, events, ipc, blocking

I'm looking for a simple event notification system:

1. Process A blocks until it gets notified by...
2. Process B, which triggers Process A.

If I was doing this in Win32 I'd likely use event objects ('A' blocks, when 'B' does a SetEvent).
I need something pretty quick and dirty (prefer script rather than C code).
What sort of things would you suggest?  I'm wondering about file advisory locks but it seems messy.  One of the processes has to actively open the file in order to hold a lock.

Comment: Well, the best way for process A (since it has nothing else to do) is to just sit in a blocking read. Could be on a socket, or a socket pair, or a pipe or a named pipe. Just sit on that filedescriptor until the juice comes in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty?

Then use [fifo](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo). It is a named pipe. The process A read from the fifo's FD with blocking mode. The process B writes to it when needed.

Simple, indeed.

And here is the bash scripting implementation:

Program A:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/event
while read -n 1 </tmp/event; do 
    echo "got message";
done
```

Program B:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "G" >>/tmp/event
```

First start script A, then in another shell window repeatedly start script B.

Comment: Ha; I totally forgot about named pipes.  Afterwards though I realized that I need to come up with a way to support read timeouts.  I hope I can still use fifos because it's elegant and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Other than fifo you can use signal and kill to essentially do interrupts and have one process sleep until it receives a signal like SIGUSR1 which then unblocks it (you can use condition variables to achieve this easily without polling).

Answer (score 0):

Slow and clean?

Then use (named) semaphores: either POSIX or SysV (not recommended, but possibly slightly more portable).  Process A does a `sem_wait` (or `sem_timedwait`) and Process B calls `sem_post`.